# "Restreaming" upload files to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, streaming, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload a file from a client to a MVC application, and then have the MVC application pass the upload file to a web api.

So far I overrode the [IHostBufferPolicySelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.hosting.ihostbufferpolicyselector(v=vs.118).aspx) to stream any incoming HTTP requests that are greater than a given size. So any large file uploads made to MVC is being received as a stream.

I thought of two solutions to this problem, but open to any suggestions.

1. Have MVC temporarily store the file, then send that file over to the web api
2. Somehow pass the stream of the file that is coming into MVC, over to the web api

Is there a way to achieve option 2? Can I pass an incoming stream to another web service?

Comment: Using `HttpPostedFileBase`? You can probably just use `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream` and pass that to the URI of your web api.

Comment: No, currently I am just reading the file contents of the request asynchronously. I would like to be able to have a MediaTypeFormatter that will parse the request and give a POCO to the controller.

Comment: Sounds really overcomplicated for what you're trying to do.